# Automate Conditional concatenation of values using Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, concatenation

I have a sample dataset as below and looking to automate the output using Python.

[image]

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['VAL1','VAL1','VAL1','VAL1','VAL2','VAL2','VAL2','VAL2','VAL3','VAL3','VAL3','VAL3'], 'C2':['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12'],'C3':['X','Y','X','Y','Z','Z','Y','X','Z','Y','Y','X']})

Condition: For all the same values in C1, corresponding values in C2 should be concatenated with a semicolon(;) and filtered by C3(only 'X' and 'Y'). How to automate it using Python?

Sample Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could user a group by and transform to join the related rows. then you can drop the duplicates

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['VAL1','VAL1','VAL1','VAL1','VAL2','VAL2','VAL2','VAL2','VAL3','VAL3','VAL3','VAL3'], 'C2':['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12'],'C3':['X','Y','X','Y','Z','Z','Y','X','Z','Y','Y','X']})
df['new'] = df[['C1','C2']].groupby(['C1']).transform(lambda x: ";".join(x))
print(df[['C1','new']].drop_duplicates())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
     C1             new
0  VAL1     A1;A2;A3;A4
4  VAL2     A5;A6;A7;A8
8  VAL3  A9;A10;A11;A12
```